# How to access variable from external js

Tags: javascript

I have external javascript file. My requirement is access external JS variable on view. Here I Have attached my Js source,

```
var tdDetailList = [];
dateFormat: "mm/dd/yyyy",

(function ($) {


    $.extend($.ui, { multiDatesPicker: { version: "1.6.4"} });


    $.fn.multiDatesPicker = function(method) {
        var mdp_arguments = arguments;
        var ret = this;
        var today_date = new Date();
        var day_zero = new Date(0);
        var mdp_events = {};


        function removeDate(date, type) {
            if(!type) type = 'picked';

            date = dateConvert.call(this, date);
            for (var i = 0; i < this.multiDatesPicker.dates[type].length; i++)

                if (!methods.compareDates(this.multiDatesPicker.dates[type][i], date))
                {
                     this.multiDatesPicker.dates[type].splice(i, 1).pop();
                     window.tdDetailList.splice(i, 1).pop();
                }
                    return this.multiDatesPicker.dates[type].sort(methods.compareDates);
        }
        function removeIndex(index, type) {
            if(!type) type = 'picked';
            return this.multiDatesPicker.dates[type].splice(index, 1).pop();
        }
        function addDate(date, type, no_sort) {
            if (!type) type = 'picked';

            date = dateConvert.call(this, date);

            // @todo: use jQuery UI datepicker method instead
            date.setHours(0);
            date.setMinutes(0);
            date.setSeconds(0);
            date.setMilliseconds(0);

            var a = date.toLocaleDateString("en-US");


            if (methods.gotDate.call(this, date, type) === false) {
                this.multiDatesPicker.dates[type].push(date);
                window.tdDetailList.push(date.toLocaleDateString("en-US"));
                if (!no_sort) this.multiDatesPicker.dates[type].sort(methods.compareDates);             
            } 
        }
```

My Html have script

```
 $('#Save').click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById("roomId").value;
        if (x == '') {
            alert("Please select room Id");
        }
        else
        {
            var url = "/Home/SaveToDatabase";

            $.post(url, { "unabailableList.UnavailableDates": window.tdDetailList, "unabailableList.RoomID": x }, function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });
        }

})
```

This script is worked properly on IE but not working on Chrome. In chrome there is an error message "tdDetailList" is undefined. Please help me to resolve this problem. simply I want to access variable from external JS on view

Comment: `there is an error message` - which line of your code triggers this error?

Comment: Make sure your `script` reference to the external file is located just before the closing `<body>` tag (`</body>`) so that by the time your script is encountered, all the HTML will have been parsed.